# ideal without invertible elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Let $R$ be a ring with unit and let $M(R)$ be a collection of all non invertible elements in $R$.
>
> Let $R\rhd I$ be a ideal such that $I\neq R$ prove that $I\subseteq M(R)$

I thought to choose some element from $I$ and suppose that the element is invertible, how can I proceed ?

Comment: Hint: Suppose $I$ contains an invertible element. Try to show that $I$ contains $1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If an ideal contains an invertible element $u$, then it contains $1=uv$, where $v$ is an inverse for $u$.